# Are function template parameters T& and T&& ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, overload-resolution, universal-reference

Consider these two overloads:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &) {}
template <typename T> void foo(T &&) {}
```

Are they potentially ambiguous?

The following code compiles with Clang 3.4, but fails with GCC 4.8, which says the overloads (first one with `T = int`, second one with `T = int&`) are ambiguous.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    foo(n);
}
```

I realize that "binding to a reference" is an "exact match" in terms of overload resolution, so I imagine that the question boils down to whether one of the deductions `T = int`/`T = int&` is preferable over the other, or if they're equally good.

Comment: @Praetorian: Thanks! I wasn't able to find this. I figured someone would have asked this before.